# ¿Cómo extraer valor especifico / campos desde un archivo txt dat o csv?

Tags: linux, unix, procesamiento-de-texto

Básicamente necesito extraer de un archivo .dat, txt, csv que contiene 7 campos con distintos valores, todos los registros el campo llamado `numdn`. Aqui un Ejemplo

```
numdn|start_date|end_date|status|ctrl_status|total_count|anchor_tstamp
92221122900|18/07/2018 13:92|18/07/2018 14:01|2|1|153122|18/07/2018 14:01
922211220900|18/07/2018 13:92|18/07/2018 14:01|2|2|83847181640|18/07/2018 14:01
922211228800|27/02/2019 11:20|27/02/2019 16:01|2|1|3922899|10/07/2019 21:09
```

Es decir, necesito que se genere una salida en un archivo que contenga solo los valores del campo "numdn"

Se que esto se puede realizar con linea de comandos de Linux, sin embargo no he podido tener exito usando grep.

Si alguien tiene alguna idea seria ideal utilizando Linux, ya que tengo mas de cien mil registros y debo extraer solo dicho valor del campo "numdn"

Gracias.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Una forma bien simple, es mediante **awk**

```
gawk -F\| '{ print $1 }' archivo.txt
```

Con `-F\|` establecemos el separador de campo, el script `{ print $1 }` imprime solo la primer columna

Otra bastante parecida es usando el comando **`cut`**

```
cut -d\| -f1 archivo.txt
```

Y ya que has mencionado `grep` si bien no pareciera ser la mejor herramienta para esto, es cierto que también es posible hacer algo como lo que pides:

```
 grep -Po '^\w+' archivo.txt
```

En este caso, usamos el modo Perl para evaluar la expresión regular (`-P`) y la opción `-o only-matching` para mostrar el solo la primer palabra antes del pipe :  `^\w+`

Comment: Me ha funcionado a la perfeccion lo siguiente: gawk '{print $2}' FS=" " file.dat > numeros.dat